# How to inspect manually decorated function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, static-analysis, python-decorators

I have a client object `Client`. It has many sync functions and I have a decorator which can change them into async functions. As I cannot modify original code, I use code like `client.send_request = async_wrapper(client.send_request)` to manually decorate all these functions.

But the problem is, a manually decorated function shows wrapper's signature but not decorated function's. For example, if I type `client.send_request`, my IDE gives me signature as `send_request(*args, **kwargs)` but not original one as `send_request(url, data, extra)`.

So that gives me a lot of difficulty while developing. Is there any way to get it work?

I'm using Pycharm, but any other IDE is acceptable.

Comment: Did you use `functools.wraps`?

Comment: @NilsWerner Sure.

Comment: You want to inspect arguments?

Comment: @warvariuc Edited.